''では'' Translating to ''According to'' in ''友人の話では'?
How does the で function in these sentences?  I've read and heard it translates to ''according to'' or ''in someone's opinion' but couldn't find any good explanation as for why. Is it similar to ''だと'' or is it about condition?
私の考えでは
友人の話では
私の経験では
''In my thoughts, in my friend's story, In my experience,'' Were my direct translations of it but let me know if I am wrong.

"''In my thoughts, in my friend's story, In my experience,'' Were my direct translations of it but let me know if I am wrong." - I don't understand why you think these things mean something different from "according to my thoughts" etc. And if you don't think so, then how is there a question remaining to ask?

Cause they do not seem like direct translations. That is why I am asking. I do not get what the purpose of the で here even is.

So are you saying you really cannot imagine how "in my friend's story" can become "according to my friend" or how "in my thoughts" can become "in my opinion"?

The concept of "direct translation" is barely even meaningful when you are talking about languages with such radically different grammar.

Regarding your three examples, it might indeed be possible to understand those expressions by assuming you can "directly" translate で as "in". If I had to choose one English word to express the function of で in your examples, it would be "scope".

Since you've posted several similar questions, let me say the following:
To be honest, I don't see much practical benefit in worrying too much about such classifications. Even if you memorize the role of で in this case, this knowledge may not be useful when you encounter another expression containing で.
で broadly marks a location, scope, method, time, condition, cause, means and so on. In English, it can be translated as "at", "in", "on", "with", "among", "for", "by", "of", "from", "due to", "according to", among others, depending on the context.
Unfortunately, even experts cannot reliably classify the roles of such particles into a finite number of categories. The number of functions for で might be 5 in one dictionary or 15 in another. It's certainly useful to read an article about で's usage tendencies at least once. However, for individual examples, you ultimately have to memorize them one by one. Here are a few examples that I struggled with when I was learning English:

100円で買う
to buy it for 100 yen
氷で出来た像
a statue made of ice
リットルで買う
to buy by the liter
3歳で英語を話す
to speak English at the age of three
心不全で死ぬ
to die from heart failure

Conversely, for example, the English preposition "in" has dozens of possible Japanese translations.
When it comes to Japanese particles and English prepositions, it takes years for learners to get used to them, but there is no easy way. Particles are inherently arbitrary, and you have to memorize various expressions without thinking too deeply about them. I still don't know why I can't say "in the age of three", "on my opinion" or "at my experience" in English, but there is usually no logic behind them. Over time, you won't need to think about particles too much.
Please also read: 後で vs. 前に. Why not the same particle?
